# Admob Interstitial Receiving Requests But Not Filling Ads

Tags: admob, interstitial, gadinterstitial

I have implemented interstitial ads into my iOS game. I have tested with test ads and I am shown these ads which confirms correct implementation.

I posted my game to the App Store 6 days ago - but still, weeks after the ad unit id was created and days after the game going live, I am still not receiving any real ads.

All requests using my real ad unit id ends with the error "Request Error: No ad to show". This means Admob is receiving the request, but there is no supplier filling the request.

I have other apps in the store that show ads fine present day, so it is not that my account is restricted or anything (no reason it should be). Has something changed in terms of requirements for ads to show?

In 6 days, I have 700 requests with 0 impressions. Frustrating since Admob help seems to disable commenting on all questions that relate to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

I guess now Admob needs a week or so after your app has been published to the store for it to register it. Once it registers, you can link it in the app settings on Admob and the ads with start showing soon after that!